# How do I get random words to display and audio to play for one of these in LUA/Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am very much a beginner to programming but would like to create an app which allows students to practice sight words.  I would like it to displays 3 random words from a table.  For one of these words I would like to have an audio file (a recording of the word) played.  The user then needs to tap that word which will be the correct answer.

I have tried looking everywhere for tutorials but I do not know enough to even be able to pick apart the code to determine what does what.  I would appreciate any direction on how to accomplish this task.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are extensive tutorials for corona. There really is no better shortcut than to start with the first one and work through them, especially if you are new to both programming in general and specifically to app development. There are also tutorals for the Lua language, and the same thing applies there. SO can help with specific questions, but as stated this question is way too broad.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm actually taking a course about Corona but have not found the tutorials, textbook, etc. very beginner-friendly.  I will continue to try and fight through though.

Comment: Possibly start with some basic tutorials for Lua then, so that you have a better footing for the programming side. Corona is a framework, and you need to learn its point of view too. Another helpful aide would be an [IDE like ZeroBrane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com/) which knows about Corona's API, can help you indent your code, and can be a debugger as well.

Comment: Also, please do ask questions here. SO welcomes (and really needs to have) questions at the beginner level as well as the expert level. We just want to see questions that can be answered, where the answer can be known to be correct.

Comment: Hi, as your question seems to be too broad, we may not able to solve it fully, but we can guide you to some tutorials. You can learn from Corona API: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/index.html , and there are several basic tutorials in: http://learningcorona.com/ . There are several other sites too, that teaches beginners. And, if you get any doubt regarding your code, syntax,structure, etc., then feel free to ask on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic demo, but should help you get started:

```
table = {
   "Hello",
   "World"
}

display.newText(table[math.random(1,#table)], 0, 0, native.systemFont, 50)
```

You will have to experiment with implementation of the sound files for yourself. Hope this helps and good luck.